# MATLAB - How to resolve "Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures" ERROR

Tags: matlab

I have a struct called A which has a [1x1] struct called B, and when I run A.B in the command line, it returns two types of answers:

```
ans = 
    X: 3
    Y: 2
    Z: 4

ans = 
    X: 1
    Y: 5
    Z: 9
    W: 4
    V: 2
```

EDIT:
What I'm trying to do is put all the values of X into a vector, so that the vector would look something like this: [3, 1, ...]

To do so, I'm first creating a vector called AB so that I can put [AB.X] into a another vector that I can use.

My current strategy is running a for loop like this one:

```
for idx = 1:length(A)
    AB(idx) = [A(idx).B];
end
```

But I get an error, "Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures." I think that's because some values of B have 3 parts while others have 5.

How can I resolve this?

Or is there a way better than using a for loop?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to put into another vector? Do you want the values of each field in your `struct`?  You are getting that when doing `A.B` because `A` is a two element struct.  The first `struct` element has three fields while the other element has five.  By doing `A.B` you are unpacking all of the `struct`s and it has nowhere else to go, so it floods the command prompt with each `struct`.

Comment: @rayryeng - I want something like this:

AB(1) = A(1).B which would give X: 2, Y: 4, Z: 2, etc etc

I also made edits in my original question

Answer (score 1):

The structs can't be concatenated together with different fields. One thing you can do to get to X is place all the struct elements into a cell array and then call cellfun to dereference X:

```
 ABX = cellfun(@(c) c.X, {A.B})
```

Resources:

[Comma separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?searchHighlight=comma%20separated%20list)

[cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html?searchHighlight=cellfun)

[Anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?searchHighlight=anonymous%20functions)

Comment: that's for your reply.

Could you give me a short example? I'm not sure what you mean by "place all the struct elements into a cell array"

Comment: The example is shown above. When you say A.B you get a "comma separated list" of values (these are the ans'es that you get in the command window. If you wrap them in curlys "{" and "}" then it is just like saying: {A(1).B, A(2).B} and so forth so they all get created in a cell array. Once they are all in a cell array you can cellfun on them to dereference the X field as you say you ultimately want

Comment: what exactly is "c" here?

Comment: The first argument to cellfun is a function handle to apply over all cells in a cell array. cellfun then passes the value in each individual cell of the cell array to this function. IN this caase, I have defined an anonymous function using the "@(c)" syntax and that anonymous function takes a single argument that I have called "c". This becomes the value of each cell in the cellfun call. As each cellis passed in, I dereference the X field to get the value and cellfun concatenates them all together.